# Java import static fails when imported class extends 3rd party lib

Tags: java, inheritance, static-import, ecj

The problem setup consists of three java libs (I stripped all package names for readability, full qualified names are used everywhere):

1. external-lib: provides the abstract class

   ```
   public abstract class AbstractExternal {}
   ```
2. my-lib-A: provides the class

   ```
   public class ClassA extends AbstractExternal {
       public static final String FOO = "foo";
   }
   ```

   `external-lib` is in my-lib-A's classpath.
3. my-lib-B statically imports FOO from ClassA:

   ```
   import static ClassA.FOO;
   public class ClassB {
       private String foo = FOO;
   }
   ```

   `my-lib-A` is in my-lib-B's classpath but `external-lib` is not.

Problem: The `import static` line produces the following error:

`The type AbstractExternal cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`.

However (1), when modifying ClassB to

```
import ClassA;
public class ClassB {
    private String foo = ClassA.FOO;
}
```

the compiler is happy.

However (2), when adding a second abstraction two my-lib-A like

```
public class AbstractClassA extends AbstractExternal {}
```

and

```
public class ClassA extends AbstractClassA {
    public static final String FOO = "foo";
}
```

the static import of ClassA.FOO in the example above works.

Question 1: Why does `import static ClassA.FOO` fails while `import ClassA` with `ClassA.FOO` works?

Question 2: Why does `import static ClassA.FOO` works when it extends another class from my-lib-A which then extends AbstractExternal?

Edit: a significant information: the compiler in question is the [Eclipse Compiler for Java](http://thecoderlounge.blogspot.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html) (ECJ).

Edit 2: javac is in sync with ECJ and is able to compile the normal import and class access in ClassB while the static import fails.

Answer (score 2):

Ecj ideally "shouldn't" report this error. I filed [Bug 533890](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533890) to track this.

The common theme behind all errors of this message *("... cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced ...")* is a conflict between:

1. wanting full semantic analysis which is aware of all relevant classes and
2. wanting resilience if the build path does not contain all classes upon which the current class (indirectly) depends.

Obviously, JLS doesn't specify how compilers should handle incomplete build paths, but as a convenience for users, no errors should be reported **if semantic analysis can avoid looking into certain indirect dependencies**.

Where and when this can indeed be avoided needs to be checked (and implemented) on a case-by-case basis, but the given example likely qualifies as a case that *can* be avoided.

Until this issue is resolved, the problem can be avoided by making `external-lib` visible also to `my-lib-B` (e.g., using a project dependency). In module systems like OSGi or JPMS, it might actually be a good idea to let `my-lib-A` "re-export" its dependency `external-lib`, since its API class `ClassA` *is* "incomplete" for clients that are unable to see `AbstractExternal`.